# Tic tac toe in C creating an alternative input

Tags: c, tic-tac-toe

I need to relearn C, part of the courese i'm working through asks to make a simple game of tic tac toe. I have the code set up to take user input as "enter row (0, 1, or 2) and column (0,  1, or 2) separated by a space" I would like to change that to simply "enter 1-9" since it is a simply 3x3 grid and that would be an easier methond to understadnd.
Thank you

```
type #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

//Initalization of the board in empty sate 
void initializeBoard(char board[3][3]) {
for(int i=0; i<3;i++){
for(int j=0; j < 3;j++){
board[i][j]= ' ';
        }
    }
}

//Printing the empty board 
void printBoard(char board[3][3]){
    printf("\n");
    printf(" %c | %c | %c \n",board[0][0],board[0][1],board[0][2]);
    printf("---|---|---\n");
    printf(" %c | %c | %c \n",board[1][0],board[1][1],board[1][2]);
    printf("---|---|---\n");
    printf(" %c | %c | %c \n",board[2][0],board[2][1],board[2][2]);
    printf("\n");
}

//Check to see if Player wins
int checkWin(char board[3][3], char player) {
    //Checks rows,columns,and diagonals for win condition
    for(int i = 0; i<3;i++){
        if(board[i][0]==player && board[i][1]==player && board[i][2]==player) {
            return 1; //Player wins
        }
        if (board[0][i]==player && board[1][i] == player && board[2][i] == player) {
            return 1; //Player wins
        }
    }
    if (board[0][0]==player && board[1][1] == player && board[2][2] == player) {
        return 1; //Player wins
    }
    if (board[0][2]==player && board[1][1] == player && board[2][0] == player) {
        return 1; //Player wins
    }
    return 0; //No winner
}

//Checks if the board is full eqauling a tie
int isBoardFull(char board[3][3]) {
    for (int i=0; i<3;i++) {
        for (int j= 0; j<3;j++) {
            if (board[i][j] == ' ') {
                return 0; //Board is not yet full
            }
        }
    }
    return 1; //Board is full 
}

// Computer's move, random placement
void computerMove(char board[3][3],char computer) {
    int row, col;
    do{
        row =rand() % 3; //Generates a random row from 0-2
        col =rand() % 3; // Generates a random column from 0-2
    } while (board[row][col] !=' ');//Repeats generatiing until empty cell is found
    board[row][col]=computer;
    printf("Computer's move:\n");
    printBoard(board);
}

int main() {
    char board[3][3];
    char playerName[10];
    char player = 'X';
    char computer = 'O';

    //Random number generator
    srand(time(NULL));

    //Initialization of the board
    initializeBoard(board);

    //request and obtain players name
    printf("Please enter your name here: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%s", playerName);
    printf(" %s you will be playing Tic Tac Toe agianst the computer, good luck.\n", playerName);

    //loop for the game
    while (1) {
        int row, col;

        // Prints the curent board config 
        printf("%s's move:\n", playerName);
        printBoard(board);

        // Get the player's move
        printf("Enter row (0, 1, or 2) and column (0, 1, or 2) separated by a space: ");
        scanf("%d %d", &row, &col);

        // Check if the chosen cell is valid and empty
        if (row >= 0 && row < 3 && col >= 0 && col < 3 && board[row][col] == ' ') {
            board[row][col] = player;

            // Check if the player has won
            if (checkWin(board, player)) {
                printf("Congratulations, %s! You win!\n", playerName);
                break;
            }

            // Check if the board is full (tie)
            if (isBoardFull(board)) {
                printf("It's a tie!\n");
                break;
            }

            // Computer's move
            computerMove(board, computer);

            // Check if the computer has won
            if (checkWin(board, computer)) {
                printf("Computer wins! Better luck next time, %s.\n", playerName);
                break;
            }

            // Check if the board is full (tie)
            if (isBoardFull(board)) {
                printf("It's a tie!\n");
                break;
            }
        } else {
            printf("Invalid move. Try again.\n");
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
here
```

I've tried to create a switch case block but i've not had any luck.

Comment: No need for switch, just some simple math: `row = (input - 1) / 3; col = (input - 1) % 3;`

Comment: Please show what you tried and we can help you get it working.

Answer (score 2):

Working and testing in parallel to the good comment noting using integer division, along with adding a couple of aesthetic improvements, following is a refactored version of your code within the "while" loop.

```
    while (1)
    {
        int row, col, position;             /* Added a position entry for 1- 9  */

        // Prints the curent board config
        printf("%s's move:\n", playerName);
        printBoard(board);

        // Get the player's move
        printf("Enter position 1 - 9: ");
        scanf("%d", &position);

        row = (position - 1) / 3;           /* Derives the row from the entry       */
        col = position - row * 3 - 1;       /* Derives the column from the entry    */

        printf("Row: %d  Col: %d\n", row, col);

        // Check if the chosen cell is valid and empty
        if (row >= 0 && row < 3 && col >= 0 && col < 3 && board[row][col] == ' ' && board[row][col] == ' ') /* Need to insure selected spot is empty    */
        {
            board[row][col] = player;

            // Check if the player has won
            if (checkWin(board, player))
            {
                printBoard(board);          /* Added to display the final board */
                printf("Congratulations, %s! You win!\n", playerName);
                break;
            }

            // Check if the board is full (tie)
            if (isBoardFull(board))
            {
                printBoard(board);          /* Added to display the final board */
                printf("It's a tie!\n");
                break;
            }

            // Computer's move
            computerMove(board, computer);

            // Check if the computer has won
            if (checkWin(board, computer))
            {
                printBoard(board);          /* Added to display the final board */
                printf("Computer wins! Better luck next time, %s.\n", playerName);
                break;
            }

            // Check if the board is full (tie)     /* Unless the computer starts the game, this test will never be true */
            if (isBoardFull(board))
            {
                printf("It's a tie!\n");
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Invalid move. Try again.\n");
        }
    }
```

Following are the key points.

- It is fairly straightforward to allow the entry of a value from "1" to "9" and convert it as noted either in the comments or the slight variation in the refactored code - done by adding the entry variable "position".
- When testing out the code, I noticed that the player could enter a position already filled, so the "if" test was refined to not allow that possibility.
- Just for aesthetics, the "printBoard" function was added when the game had been decided (win/lose/tie).
- Also, since the player always gets the first move, that final "board is full" condition would not occur after the computer move, so it could be omitted unless the program is further refined to randomly allow the computer to go first.

With that, following are some sample terminal outputs.

```
Enter position 1 - 9: 9
Row: 2  Col: 2

 X | O | X 
---|---|---
   | X |   
---|---|---
 O | O | X 

Congratulations, Craig! You win!

Enter position 1 - 9: 5
Row: 1  Col: 1
Computer's move:

 X | O | X 
---|---|---
 X | X |   
---|---|---
 O | O | O 

Computer wins! Better luck next time, Craig.

Enter position 1 - 9: 8
Row: 2  Col: 1

 X | O | O 
---|---|---
 O | X | X 
---|---|---
 X | X | O 

It's a tie!
```

The takeaway from this would be to probably delve into some "C" tutorials some more in regard to integer division, and array indices along with the output "look and feel".